# (Android) How to set hyperlink to a textview inside ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview containing some news. Each news is a row which comtains a title, content, publisher and date. Now I want to set hyperlinks to every title TextView. How to implement that? The following is my code:

```
private void show_news() {
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    get_data(list);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.News_List);
    SimpleAdapter adp = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list, R.layout.news_item, new String[]{"news_title", "news_content", "news_publisher", "news_date"}, new int[]{R.id.news_title, R.id.news_content, R.id.news_publisher, R.id.news_date});
    lv.setAdapter(adp);
    /* the code above runs properly*/
    /*Now I want to set hyperlink to my title TextView..*/

}
```

This is my news_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_publisher"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/news_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am new to Android programming. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout) adp.getView(0, null, lv);
TextView title = (TextView)first.getChildAt(0);
```

That doesn't necessarily get the first element of the list view.  It doesn't even necessarily get the first element on screen.  That's very implementation specific (you're assuming the list view doesn't have any children other than its rows, which is actually wrong in many cases).

If you want to change the first item of a list view, do

```
Item item = adb.getItem(0)
item.title= "New Title"
adp.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have solved it. I have updated my post and raised another qustion, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the SimpleAdapter and use the derived adapter. When you extend the adapter, set the hyperlink property for the title by calling:

```
<the title textview>.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

in the method getView method of the adapter. A commonly used approach in Android ListView adapter is to use a so called view holder, which is a key technique to get better listview performance, and you can check the details from the developer document: [Hold View Objects in a View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Suppose you employ this approach, the code would looks more or less like:

```
 holder.titleView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

If your textview does not have a URL, then you can set the text in HTML form as:

```
holder.titleView.setText(
    Html.fromHtml(
        "<a href=\"http://www.someurl.com\">Breaking News</a> "));
holder.titleView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: thanks. but I think your approach works when the textview contains url. what if the textview doesn't contain a url? then how to bind them together?